# performClick not triggering

Tags: java, android

I am trying to trigger a click on the Carousel. I want that if I press the forward button, it automatically triggers the click on the carousel and then move forward. The manual click (physical touch) is working but performClick() is not. The code is as follows

```
//************* Forward Button: Select Objects *************
    Button forwardButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.ForwardButton);
    forwardButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent i = new Intent(NewFieldTrip.this, SelectObjects.class);
         //ImagePosition = (int)carousel.getSelectedItemId();
          carousel.performClick();
          i.putExtra("SelectedScene",ImagePosition);
          startActivity(i);

      }
    });

    carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {                
        Toast.makeText(NewFieldTrip.this, "Select Position=" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ImagePosition = position;
    }

  });
```

A helping hand would be great :)

EDIT:

```
public void scrollToChild(int i){       

    CarouselImageView view = (CarouselImageView)getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
    float angle = view.getCurrentAngle();

    if(angle == 0)
        return;

    if(angle > 180.0f)
        angle = 360.0f - angle;
    else
        angle = -angle;

    mFlingRunnable.startUsingDistance(-angle);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

What type is **carousel** of? ListView?

So if carousel is ListView then what event are you expected on ListView clicking?

**performClick()** trigger **OnClickListener**, which you didn't set to ***cаrousel***. You set **OnItemClickListener**, so you have to call **performItemClick(...)**. Try it.

**UPD:**

Try to do folowing:

**1)** make method **Carousel.scrollToChild(int i)** public

**2)**

```
int itemCount = carousel.getAdapter().getCount();
int item = new Random().nextInt(itemCount);
View view - carousel.getAdapter().getView(item, null, null);
int itemId = carousel.getAdapter().getItemId(item);
carousel.scrollToChild(item);
carousel.performItemClick(view, item, itemId);
```

Comment: okay that does make sense, i am implementing a 3d carousel on this link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androcarousel.aspx?fid=1605167&select=4059472&fr=1 ... i want to perform an item click anywhere on the carousel to trigger what i want, the three parameters are view, position, row id, i cant figure them out now :s

Comment: Do you want to perform click on random carousel element?

Comment: sry, had a power breakdown .. actually i want to perform a click anywhere on the carousel, that makes it random .. but i dont understand the need for view, position and row id, cant i just call it simply?

Comment: if i just skip the auto click part, i achieve my goal by clicking anywhere on the carousel and proceeding with another button, i want to automate the click on the carousel